# asp core Lockout not set LockoutEnabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin

Initialize an Identity with automatic user locking after 3 login attempt in Startup.cs

```cs
var lockoutOptions = new LockoutOptions()
{
    AllowedForNewUsers = true,
    DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
    MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3
};
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(x =>
{
    x.Lockout = lockoutOptions;
})
```

Login in AccountController.cs

```cs
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

1. Initial database state

[image]

2. First failure login

[image]

3. Second failure login

[image]

4. Third failure login

[image]

**In final**

*LockoutEnd = + one year (all ok)*

*LockoutEnabled == 0 (false)* **user not locked and can login**

**Why 'LockoutEnabled' not 1 (true)**

**Which reasons can be?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LockoutEnabled` property indicates, that a user CAN be locked out. It does NOT mean, that the user IS currently banned.

> Gets or sets a flag indicating if the user could be locked out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.lockoutenabled?view=aspnetcore-2.1

This way you could setup "normal" users with LockoutEnabled=true and some "special admin users" that have LockoutEnabled=false. (Would be bad if "evil people" lockout your admins by simply trying to login a few times - just as an example, where this could make sense.)

If LockoutEnabled defaults to true for new users is configured using

```
LockoutOptions.AllowedForNewUsers
```

> Gets or sets a flag indicating whether a new user can be locked out.
>   Defaults to true.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.lockoutoptions.allowedfornewusers?view=aspnetcore-2.1

It's set to true in your code example, so I guess you changed it after creating your test user or did a database update somewhere / for testing, so you'll have to manually set it to true in your database for all existing users. (new users should be added correctly.)

Comment: It is possible that there is a bug -- probably in docs or in code. UserManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync method has this description: "Sets a flag indicating whether the specified user is locked out..."